# Issue with for loop - Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to clean up a df using Pandas. I have a column containing four possible things:

1. X.X lbs
2. X.X pounds
3. X.X ounces
4. NaN

---

```
df.weight.fillna(0, inplace=True)
for i in [0, df.weight.size-1]:
    cell = df.weight[i]
    while (cell == 0 and i < df.weight.size-1):
        i += 1
        cell = df.weight[i]
    if (cell != 0):
        number = ''.join([x for x in cell if (x.isdigit() or 
        if bool(re.search('ounces', cell)):
            df.loc[i, 'weight'] = number * 0.0625    # Ounces to pounds conversion
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'weight'] = number
```

The aim of the code above is to iterate through the rows of 'weight' and check:

- if cell == 0 -> just skip (causes problems when I try to use the regex, thus 
  the while loop);
- if cell has 'ounces' -> keep only numbers and '.'; convert number to pounds
- if cell has 'lbs' or 'pounds' -> just keep numbers and '.'

So, ideally an entry like '1.0 pounds' should become '1.0' and an entry like '1 ounces' should become '0.0625'.

What I get instead is that this code only changes the first occurrence ('1.0 lbs' -> '1.0') whilst leaving the others untouched

input:

2.1 pounds - 5.5 lbs - 8.8 ounces - 0

Output:

2.1 - 5.5 - 0.55 - 0

Comment: Please provide some real input and expected output data.

Comment: Also correct your indent under the first `for` statement

Comment: done :) ty for pointing out

Comment: Isn't it simply [**`\d+(?:\.\d+)?`**](https://regex101.com/r/VefAzG/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python this

```
 for i in [0, df.weight.size-1]:
```

means a loop over the *list* `[0, df.weight.size-1]` of two items, `0`, and `df.weight.size-1`.  You probably meant something like this:

```
for i in range(df.weight.size)
```

or something similar.  I suspect your code has some other problems as well but that's the first one.

By the way, if you have some transformation you'd like to apply to each item in a series, define a function that implements that transformation for a *single* item, and then apply it to all items using [`Series.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply).  In this case like `df.weight = df.weight.apply(your_function)`.  Things get a bit more complicated if the transformation depends on other values in the series, but that does not appear to be the case here.